# Extracting Key-worlds out of string and show them in another column

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to write a query to extract specific names out of String and have them show in another column for example a column has this field

Column:
*Row 1*: jasdhj31e31jh123hkkj,12l1,3jjds,Amin,02323rdcsnj
*Row 2*:jasnasc8918212,ahsahkdjjMina67,
*Row 3*:kasdhakshd,asda,asdasd,121,121,Sina878788kasas

**Key Words: Amin,Mina,Sina**

How could I have these key words in another column? I dont want to insert another column but if that's the only solution let me know.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should improve the formatting of you row data. It's currently quite hard to understand.

Comment: what the logic for extracting those keywords? do you have those keywords list pre-defined and just need to detect which ones present in which row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH keywords AS (
  SELECT keyword
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('Amin,Mina,Sina')) keyword
)
SELECT str, STRING_AGG(keyword) keywords_in_str
FROM `project.dataset.table`
CROSS JOIN keywords
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, CONCAT(r'(?i)', keyword))
GROUP BY str
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'jasdhMINAj31e31jh123hkkj,12l1,3jjds,Amin,02323rdcsnj' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jasnasc8918212,ahsahkdjjMina67,' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'kasdhakshd,asda,asdasd,121,121,Sina878788kasas' 
), keywords AS (
  SELECT keyword
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('Amin,Mina,Sina')) keyword
)
SELECT str, STRING_AGG(keyword) keywords_in_str
FROM `project.dataset.table`
CROSS JOIN keywords
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, CONCAT(r'(?i)', keyword))
GROUP BY str
```

with results as

```sql
Row str                                                     keywords_in_str  
1   jasdhMINAj31e31jh123hkkj,12l1,3jjds,Amin,02323rdcsnj    Amin,Mina    
2   jasnasc8918212,ahsahkdjjMina67,                         Mina     
3   kasdhakshd,asda,asdasd,121,121,Sina878788kasas          Sina
```

Comment: But the column has hundreds of row and I can't add all the row in select. So is there anyway I can write it to look in each row instead of adding each string in SELECT 'jasdhMINAj31e31jh123hkkj,12l1,3jjds,Amin,02323rdcsnj' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jasnasc8918212,ahsahkdjjMina67,' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'kasdhakshd,asda,asdasd,121,121,Sina878788kasas'

Comment: see update. so hopefully it is more clear for you now how to use answer. just replace `project.dataset.table` with your real table reference

Comment: when I'm adding my criteria in this query I'm getting the error that Unrecognized name: str at [8:23]. I dont know whats the problem with the query. could you please advise!                                                                    WITH keywords AS (
  SELECT keyword
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('a,b,s')) keyword
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(keyword) keywords_in_str
FROM `xxx`
  CROSS JOIN keywords
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(keyword, CONCAT(r'(?i)'))
GROUP BY str

Comment: what is your criteria?!! how I can say something w/o seeing it :o)

Comment: that's obvious  - there is no str column in output SELECT so obviously nothing to GROUP BY !! also, you query in comment - looks quite different from the one in this post - in any case  - if you have new questions  - please post a new one! Format of comments does not allow answer with needed quality. so - as I said  - post new question and we will help you further

Answer (score 0):

to count the no of keywords

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'jasdhMINAj31e31jh123hkkj,12l1,3jjds,Amin,02323rdcsnj' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jasnasc8918212,ahsahkdjjMina67,' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'kasdhakshd,asda,asdasd,121,121,Sina878788kasas' 
)
select str,array(select as struct countif(lower(x) ="amin") amin,countif(lower(x) ="mina") mina,countif(lower(x)="sina") sina from unnest(x)x)keyword from
(select str,regexp_extract_all(str,"(?i)(Amin|Mina|Sina)")x from `project.dataset.table`)
```